# Install PEAR on project local?

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, pyrus

How to install pear on project local?
Only install system global (and copy manually to project local) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answers @greg0ire provided (+1) should work out.

If you are using PHP 5.3 you can also look into "the next version of the pear installer" [pyrus](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/pyrus.commands.php).

It can make it easier mainting different configurations

Answer (score 2):

See this page of the manual : [Installation of a local PEAR copy on a shared host](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php)